# How to export an OpenCV Java project to .jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, jar

I am new to OpenCV.

I have a project that uses OpenCV to read video feed from a video file and detect motion in each frame.

The code runs smoothly in Eclipse. But problem comes when I was trying to export it to a .jar file.

I export the code as a "Runnable JAR file" and select "Package required libraries into generated JAR" option in Eclipse. I tried to run the code through java command. But it gives following error.

```
C:\Users\Zhang\Documents\B-ACS>java -jar exp.jar
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2411 in
      java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at cvTest3.VideoCaptureDemo.<clinit>(VideoCaptureDemo.java:33)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
           der.java:56)
```

The code  at line 33 is:

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

How should I export the code into a JAR file?

Comment: I think you've exported to the JAR just fine.  The trick now is configuring your system so when it runs it will be able to find the native libs it needs.  You did that in eclipse, not sure how to do it outside, may be as easy as including some opencv dirs in your system path.

Comment: @medloh Thank you! I solved the issue by specify the -Djava.library.path.